# Link only answer when the the question is asking for a link

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

I just noticed this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916109/net-binding-for-allegro/25305069#25305069

I was about to flag it as link only but noticed that the asker specifically wants a link it seems. On the other hand I think the whole question may not be suitable, but I think this answer does fundamentally answer it.

What should I do about a link answer (perhaps to a bad question) but where the questions is basically just seeking a link?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Flagging totally proper action to take.

Comment: @mohacs: Yes but the flag goes on the question, not the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion would be to first vote to close the off-topic question that is asking for a recommendation (I've now done this).

Second, comment to the user that the quality of their answer isn't up to the standards that we expect, that we prefer answers that are self-contained and don't need the link.  If you feel that the answer isn't helpful, then downvote it.

In this case it also seems that they were trying to give a new link location for one of the other answers, so you could mention that they can suggest an edit or you can edit the new link in yourself.